# Make independent child to have 100% height of parent without explicit height

Tags: css

I know this is a very common question, but all answers I saw looked hackish, and I'm looking for a solution more scalable.

The parent has a `min-height` and `max-height` but no explicit height. We want the parent to be at least X (never bigger than Y) but let it grow with content.
The child should be 100% height of its parent and center the elements.

```
.parent {
  min-height: 400px
  max-height: 800px
 }
  
.child {
  height: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
}
```

There is a chance to do it without connecting these to elements? Like flexbox parent with flex grown on the child? This is important because I would prefer to keep parent as block element.

Comment: Who is "We"? =D

Comment: That matters? It may be I, you, she/he or they. In this case, because it's just because I hope we (community) will try to figure out a solution.

Comment: Good point, I just noticed it. =D

Comment: Nope the parent needs to have a determinable height